# Solr: Pivot faceting with MoreLikeThis handler

Tags: solr, lucene, facet, morelikethis

I'm currently using Solr 4.10.3. While faceting on a field works fine with the MoreLikeThis handler, it seems it's not working for pivoting. I'm trying with a simple query:

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/mlt?q=id:someid&facet=true&facet.pivot=uid,doctype

This query returns an empty **facet_counts** result, but works fine if I'm using the SearchHandler.

Is this a known limitation for using faceting with the MLT handler, and if yes, what is the reason? Or is it a bug?